# Change ControlTemplate of ContentControl in View using MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, controltemplate

I have two resources Dock and Undock in my View which is a UserControl(Dock.xaml), Following is xaml code

```
<Grid>
    <ContentControl Template="{StaticResource Dock}"/>   
</Grid>
```

In DockViewModel there is property called IsDocked,if its true i need to apply Dock otherwise Undock template

How to change the template in view using ViewModel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<ContentControl>
        <ContentControl.Style>
            <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                <Setter Property="ContentControl.Template"  Value="{StaticResource Dock}"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsDocked}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="ContentControl.Template"  Value="{StaticResource UnDock}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ContentControl.Style>
    </ContentControl>
```